# Siding separation after 5 months

Tags: siding

I wanted to see if anyone had any insight to siding separation. I had this done 5 months ago and went thru a semi brutal winter. I’m wondering if this is normal to see separation. I have not checked if there was flashing on the joints. But update as soon as I get home. https://imgur.com/a/WSpff06

Comment: What kind of siding is this (wood, composite, fiber cement, etc)? What was done for the joints? If this is a wood product, it will expand and contract, opening these gaps. The install instructions likely specified backing the joints with a water barrier (e.g. tyvek) and caulking the joints to keep the building protected. Not all caulking is created equal, especially for outdoor applications.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Hardie plank siding.

The installation guide can be found [here](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/d8/d8e5c4e7-8d56-4098-8c70-4cb1d36aeb90.pdf)

It recommends that flashing be behind the ends of boards, but caulking can be done as well.